# Creating a linked list without pointers but indices

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

My teacher wants me to create something like linked list but using indices instead of pointers. So the `Node` contains `int data` and `int index`.

Can you drop me a hint how would I do that? I know how to create it with pointers but how to do without them? He mentioned pool as a container though.

Comment: You use linked lists in C, in C++ you just use `std::map`.

Comment: Arrays and use array indexes as links?

Comment: Also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/

Comment: You could use std::vector, but it wouldn't be linked list

Comment: @Havenard, linked list and std::map are different structures, you can't replace one of them by other

Comment: @devalone Hold my beer.

Comment: @Havenard, OK, make efficient key-value structure, where keys are sorted and unique using linked list

Comment: @devalone There's also `std::list` which is basically a linked list underneath. But when you have an index you probably want to use `std::map`.

Comment: @Havenard I know.
> But when you have an index you probably want to use std::map
When I have index, I use std::vector, when I need key-value structure, I use std::map

Comment: @devalone The thing of `std::vector` is that it requires contiguous memory (reallocs when resized) and contiguous index (0 to n-1), so if your index is a custom range or is not contiguous, even if they are ordered, `std::vector` wont do.

Comment: @Havenard, why you're telling me it? I know it. I just tried to say, that you should use things for what they are invented for.

Comment: @devalone And I'm saying `std::vector` neither works as a linked list or offers true indexing.

Comment: @Havenard, yes, just linked list works exactly as linked list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your struct `Node` would be like this

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    int index; // index of the entry in the pool to the next node
}
```

You can use a `vector` or array to create a pool

```
vector<Node*> pool; // stores the pointer to next nodes
```

Now to access the next node you can do

```
Node* nextNode = pool[currNode->index];
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach would be to use an array of `Nodes` where each node stores an (array) index to the `prev` and `next` `Node`. Thus, your `Node` would look something like:

```
struct Node 
{
    T data;
    int prev;    // index of the previous Node of the list
    int next;    // index of the next Node of the list
}
```

Additionally, you will probably have to dynamically allocate the `Node` array, implement some bookkeeping to *get* and *free* space in the array: for example a `bool` array that stores the unoccupied indexes in the `Node` array, along with two functions that will update it every time a new `Node` / index is added or removed (it will be fragmented as nodes won't be always contiguous); find an index of a `Node` in the array: for example by subtracting the address of the `Node` from the first address of the array.

Here is how a possible interface of a doubly linked list using the above technique would look like:

```
template <typename T>                          // T type Node in your case
class DList
{
    T** head;                                  // array of pointers of type Node
    int first;                                 // index of first Node
    int last;                                  // index of last Node

    bool* available;                           // array of available indexes 
    int list_size;                             // size of list

    int get_index();                           // search for index with value true in bool available
    void return_index(int i);                  // mark index as free in bool available

    std::ptrdiff_t link_index(T*& l) const     // get index of Node

    void init();                               // initialize data members
    void create();                             // allocate arrays: head and available

    void clear();                              // delete array elements
    void destroy();                            // delete head

public:
    DList();                                   // call create() and init()
    ~DList();                                  // call clear() and destroy()

    void push_back(T* l);
    void push_front(T* l);
    void insert(T*& ref, T* l);                // insert l before ref

    T* erase(T* l);                            // erase current (i.e. l) and return next
    T* advance(T* l, int n);                   // return n-th link before or after currnet

    std::size_t size() const;
    int capacity () const { return list_size; }
};
```

You could use that as a benchmark and implement something on your own.

```
template <typename T>
void DList<T>::push_back(T* l)
{
    if (l == nullptr)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Dlist::push_back()::Null pointer as argument!\n");
    }

    int index = get_index();
    head[index] = l;

    if (last != -1)
    {
        head[last]->next = index;
        head[index]->prev = last;
    }
    else
    {
        first = index;
        head[index]->prev = -1;
    }

    last = index;
    head[index]->next = -1;
}
```